# How can I prevent a partial view from disappearing upon submit?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I’m using BeginForm inside of a child view.  When I submit the form I’m still on the parent view but the child view goes away.  I would like for the information to be submitted but the form to remain until the user wants to load another partial view or move away from the page entirely.  Is there a way to prevent the page from disappearing upon submit?  Here’s what my BeginForm looks like:

```
 using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new { fromTeacherPage = true, searchTeacher =     instructorName, selectedDepartment = Model.Assignments.FirstOrDefault().departmentNumber, id = Model.Assignments.FirstOrDefault().InstructorId, strCategoryName = @ViewBag.categoryname }, FormMethod.Post, new { @name = "formName", @class = "nameOfClass" }))
{

 //code for form here

 <button id="submitButton" class="submitButton">Submit</button><br />
  }
```

UPDATE:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datep").datepicker({ showOn: "both", buttonText: "Select Date", changeMonth: true,      changeYear: true, yearRange: "-2:+2", showOtherMonths: true, onSelect: function (date, datepickder) {
        var sltdDate = { selectedDate: date };

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Schedule/GetSchedule",
            data: sltdDate,

            datatype: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#returnedData").html(data);
                $("#returnedData #dateContainer").remove();
                $("<button>Hide</button>").appendTo("#homeworkUpdateId-0")


            }
        });

    }




       });

   });
 </script>
 @{

     int? intTeacherID = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["intTeacherId"]);
     string instructorName = (from x in Model.Enrollments where x.InstructorId == intTeacherID select x.InstructorFullName).FirstOrDefault();



   }




 <div id="dateContainer">
   <label for ="datep">Date: </label><input id="datep" />

   </div>

    <div id="returnedData">


   @if (Model.Assignments != null)
   {



      using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new { fromTeacherPage = true, searchTeacher = instructorName, selectedDepartment = Model.Assignments.FirstOrDefault().departmentNumber, id = Model.Assignments.FirstOrDefault().teacherId, strCategoryName = @ViewBag.categoryname }, FormMethod.Post, new { @name = "formName", @class = "submitAttendance" }))
    {


 <table>
     <tr>
        <th>
          Grade
     </th>



    <th>
      Attendance
    </th>


    <th>
    Clas Day
    </th>
    <th>
   Assignment Type
    </th>
    <th>
   Overall Grade
    </th>
    </tr>

     @foreach (var assignment in Model.Assignments.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i }))
     {









    int asgnIndex = assignment.Index;

    <tr id="rowId+@asgnIndex">

    <td>


               <div id="homeworkUpdateId-@asgnIndex">
                  @Html.TextBox("HomeworkGrade", assignment.Data.HomeworkGrade.ToString(), new { style = "width:55px; text-align: center" })
               </div>
    </td>

     </table>
    <button id="submitButton" class="submitButton">Submit </button><br />
   }
  }

  </div>
```

Comment: When you say a child view you mean a partial view? also if you add how your parent view looks like we can help you. Also remember that when you use BeginForm the whole page will be updated if you want to reload just a part of your view you should use @using (Ajax.BeginForm()){}

Comment: I added most of the partial view.  Mostly omitted table rows for simplicity.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong so whenever you select a date you are doing a get and you pass the selected date to the controller, base on this you set your model and return it to the view and you replace everything inside <div id="returnedData"> with your results? this will make everything inside <div id="returnedData"> be replaced including your form, also when you do a post using Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller"... are you calling a different view or you want to update the current view after the post?

Comment: Yes the date triggers the call to the controller returning in the returnedData div.  I then make changes to the form and post with html.beginForm of the form contained in my returnedData div.  I want to have the post happen but the user can stay on the form to change other things if needed until they're ready to navigate from the form.

Comment: why are you not using  @Html.Partial("partialview", subModel)

Comment: Just changing Html.BeginForm to Ajax.BeginForm did the trick as Moises suggested.  Thanks guys!

Comment: I'm glad this help you I add the answer so it can help someone else :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using

```
using(Html.BeginForm()){}
```

this will refresh the whole page if you only want to reload some section inside your view you have to use

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", null, new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "divToUpdate", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET"}, new {id = "someIdFOrm"}))
```